# Testing DAO with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, sequel

I'm working in a project which involves ruby, sequel and sinatra. I read about which testing framework to use, and RSpec seems to be the most used by the community.

The project consists in a CRUD application, using DAO as the persistence pattern.

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite
DB.create_table :foos do
  primary_key :id
  int :foo_attribute1
  int :foo_attribute2
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :id, :foo_attribute1, :foo_attribute2
end

module FooDAO
  extend self

  def save(f)
    DB[:foos].insert(foo_attribute1: f.foo_attribute1, foo_attribute2: f.foo_attribute2)
  end

  def [](id)
    DB[:foos].where(id: id).first
  end

  def update(f)
    DB[:foos].where(id: f.id).update(foo_attribute1: f.foo_attribute1, foo_attribute2: f.foo_attribute2)
  end

  def count
    DB[:foos].count
  end
end

describe FooDAO do
  context 'save' do
    f = Foo.new
    f.foo_attribute1 = 1
    f.foo_attribute2 = 2
    FooDAO.save f
    it { expect(FooDAO.count).to eq 1 }
  end

  context 'get' do
    it { expect(FooDAO[1][:foo_attribute1]).to eq 1 }
    it { expect(FooDAO[1][:foo_attribute2]).to eq 2 }
  end

  context 'update' do
    f = Foo.new
    f.id = 1
    f.foo_attribute1 = 2
    f.foo_attribute2 = 3
    FooDAO.update f
    it { expect(FooDAO[1][:foo_attribute1]).to eq 2 }
    it { expect(FooDAO[1][:foo_attribute2]).to eq 3 }
  end
end
```

In this case, the `get` context won't pass the examples. But if I comment the `update` context, they will.

I also found that if I change the `get` context, it will pass them all

```
context 'get' do
  h = FooDAO[1]
  it { expect(h[:foo_attribute1]).to eq 1 }
  it { expect(h[:foo_attribute2]).to eq 2 }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the fact that you've wrapped other code in your context block instead of within the test statement (the `it` block).

Try this:

```
describe FooDAO do
  context 'save' do
    it "saves a Foo" do
      original_count = FooDAO.count
      f = Foo.new
      f.foo_attribute1 = 1
      f.foo_attribute2 = 2
      FooDAO.save f
      expect(FooDAO.count).to eq(original_count + 1)
    end
  end

  context 'get' do
    let!(:foo) do
      f = Foo.new
      f.foo_attribute1 = 1
      f.foo_attribute2 = 2
      FooDAO.save f
      f
    end

    it { expect(FooDAO[foo.id][:foo_attribute1]).to eq 1 }
    it { expect(FooDAO[foo.id][:foo_attribute2]).to eq 2 }
  end

  context 'update' do
    let!(:foo) do
      f = Foo.new
      f.id = 1
      f
    end

    before(:each)
      foo.foo_attribute1 = 2
      foo.foo_attribute2 = 3
      FooDAO.update foo
    end

    it { expect(FooDAO[1][:foo_attribute1]).to eq 2 }
    it { expect(FooDAO[1][:foo_attribute2]).to eq 3 }
  end
end
```

Comment: In the `get` context, you are saving 2 more instances

Comment: But I totally get the point, I mustn't write statements in contexts.

Comment: No, I'm not clearing it. I don't think it's ok to do that. Is it? Why do you say that? What I do is, everytime I run `rspec`, it deletes the file `database.db`, creates a new one with some predefined data, and then run all the tests. Feel free to criticize it and to tell me how to improve it :)

Comment: I usually clear my DB between test runs, but I don't know enough about your test suite to know if it makes sense.  Anyway, I modified the tests a bit to be agnostic to whether or not other things exist in the DB.  Can you try them now?